# solving a system with homogeneous coordinates

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I have an equation  $$\boldsymbol{r - Pr_P} = (\boldsymbol{Qr_Q - Pr_P})t$$

where, $$\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&z_P\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}cos\phi&0&sin\phi&0\\0&1&0&0\\-sin\phi&0&cos\phi&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\boldsymbol{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&z_Q\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\boldsymbol{r} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix}, \boldsymbol{r_P} = \begin{bmatrix}\chi\\\psi\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \boldsymbol{r_Q} = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} $$

I am trying to solve for $a$ and $b$ by eliminating $t$ but, what I get as an answer is different from the correct answer given, which is $$a\:=\:x\:+\:\frac{\left(z\:-\:z_Q\right)\left(x\:-\:\chi \right)}{z_{P\:}-\:z\:+\:\chi tan\phi }$$,  $$b\:=\:y\:+\:\frac{\left(z\:-\:z_Q\right)\left(y\:-\:\psi \right)}{z_{P\:}-\:z\:+\:\chi tan\phi }$$

The problem is in my computation (provided the answer is truly correct) but I am unable to figure out where. For example, what I get as $a$ and $b$ are:
$$a=\frac{xz_Q\:-z_Q\chi cos\phi \:-\:xz\:+z\chi cos\phi }{z\:-\:z_P\:+\:\chi sin\phi }$$

$$b\:=y+\:\frac{\left(y\:-\psi \right)\left(z\:-\:z_Q\right)}{z_P\:-z\:+\:\chi sin\phi }$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got 
$$a=x+\frac{(\chi \cos(\phi)-x)(z - z_Q)}{z - z_{P} + \chi \sin(\phi)}$$
and
$$b=y+\frac{(\psi-y)(z - z_Q)}{z - z_P + \chi \sin(\phi)}$$
apparently, there is something wrong with your allegedly correct solution.